# Adding tiles in the panorama page

Tags: windows-phone-7

Can we add tiles in one of the sections in panorama or i need to implement it using button(changing the style of the button, so that it appears like a tile)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `tile` control, so you'll have to create your own. You can do this by styling a button, like you said, or using an Image control.

Answer (score 0):

There is no framework control that gives a tile layout. However, it is very easy to template Buttons so that they are simply rectangular squares of colour, allowing you to use them as tiles:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TileTemplate">
  <Button Width="160" Height="160"
          Margin="10">
    <Grid>
      <Rectangle Fill="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>

      <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
    </Grid>
  </Button>
</DataTemplate>
```

You can then host them within a Silverlight Toolkit `WrapPanel`

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but a project does now exist.  Take a look at the [TileSlider](http://tileslider.codeplex.com/) project